# Go unpacking array as arguments to path.Join

Tags: go

I want to unpack string array and pass to path.Join

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    p := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    fmt.Println(path.Join(p...))
}
```

Output of this code is:

```
a/b/c
```

But if I pass arguments like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    p := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    fmt.Println(path.Join("d", p...))
}
```

It doesn't work.

```
tmp/sandbox299218161/main.go:10: too many arguments in call to path.Join
    have (string, []string...)
    want (...string)
```

I think I have misunderstanding on unpacking, any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not misunderstanding anything really, you just can't do that. The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) says:

> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.

In short, `p...` can only be used as the *entire* variadic part of the arguments, because when you do that, it simply re-uses `p` as the parameter slice within the function, instead of making a new one.

If you want to add some arguments at the beginning, you would have to construct your own slice with all of the arguments first, something like:

```
p := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
p2 := append([]string{"d"}, p...)
fmt.Println(path.Join(p2...))
```

which works alright and prints "d/a/b/c".